# Testing spring security protected pages

Tags: grails, spock, geb

I am trying to test that my home page is protected by Spring Security using Geb.

This is my test:

```
void "Unauthenticated user is redirected to login page."() {
given:
    to HomePage
    via AuthPage

expect:
    at AuthPage
```

}

When I try to run this test geb says that my assertion failed. It says that I am in my AuthPage and not my HomePage.

This is the stacktrace:

```
| Failure:  Unauthenticated user is redirected to login page.(home.HomePageSpec)
|  Assertion failed: 
title ==~ /Home/
|     |
Login false
at pages.home.HomePage._clinit__closure1(HomePage.groovy:8)
at geb.Page.verifyThisPageAtOnly(Page.groovy:165)
at geb.Page.verifyAt(Page.groovy:133)
at geb.Browser.doAt(Browser.groovy:358)
at geb.Browser.at(Browser.groovy:289)
at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:436)
at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:412)
at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:51)
at home.HomePageSpec.Unauthenticated user is redirected to login page.(HomePageSpec.groovy:22)
```

But this is the behavior I am expecting! Why is it failing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `via()` which was introduced for situations involving redirects, which goes to page url just like `to()` does but it doesn't do "at checking". So your test would look like:

```
void "Unauthenticated user is redirected to login page."() {
    when: 
    via HomePage

    then:
    at AuthPage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `to()` method of geb implicitly calls the static `at closure`. That's why my tests failed. When I called to `HomePage` it would check that I reached the `HomePage` which I never do because it gets redirected. I used `go <HOME_PAGE_URL>` instead.

Comment: You could improve your code by using `via HomePage` (goes to HomePage url and does not do `at` checking) and `at AuthPage`. That way you don't have to put your page url in your test when using `go()`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I still go to the AuthPage when I use via HomePage.

Comment: Yes, cause you are redirected by your application.

Comment: It doesn't work. It says that I'm failing an assertion. go is the only thing that seems to work.